# Using a static_assert to determine if a specific template parameter is a specific untyped class template

Tags: c++, c++11

I'd like to have a function that restricts the parameters to be only types that derive from a specific templated class. In this case, `basic_string` (from the STL-[docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)). For example, a `wstring` is declared:

```
typedef basic_string<wchar_t, char_traits<wchar_t>, allocator<wchar_t> >
wstring;
```

The basic idea would be something like this:

```
template <class TString>
void strings_only_please(TString message) {
    static_assert(is_base_of<basic_string, TString>::value, 
        "Not a string type!");  
}
```

Of course, that doesn't compile though as basic_string hasn't been specified ... it needs a real type. (While I could likely just hard code the few actual string types, I'm looking for  a general solution to this pattern.)

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and would ideally like the code to be portable to other modern C++ compilers, like GCC.

Comment: Do you mean "derive" as in derived class, or do you mean specializations of std::basic_string? Note that it's a bad idea to actually derive a class from std::basic_string.

Comment: Derived classes, something that is a `basic_string<T1, T2, T3>`.

Comment: a specialization of `std::basic_string<T1,T2,T3>` (as `std::string` (which is `std::basic_string<char>`) is called a *specialization*, it isn't "*derived*".

Comment: @refp - Ack. My C# hat was on. Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are three ways of solving your problem, one would be an implementation of `is_specialization_of`, the other involves making your function take a `std::basic_string<T1,T2,T3>` instead of `TString`, and the third has the same philosophy as the 2nd solution; make a template matchable only by `std::basic_string`.

---

`is_base_of` isn't sufficient in your example because of two reasons:

1. `is_base_of` is used to see if type `U` is derived from `T` (or if it's the same type), in your snippet there is no inheritance involved.
2. `std::basic_string` isn't a complete type and therefore can't be used with `is_base_of` at all (which you already pointed out).

---

**solution #1**

`is_specialization_of` would be used to check whether type `U` is a specialization of the *incomplete* type `T`. It's quite easy to implement it using a template-template class, as in the below example.

<sup>*as noted by @SebastianRedl variadic templates are not available using VS2012, see the other solutions (which are not as generic but still sufficient to your needs).*</sup>

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<template<typename...> class T, typename U>
struct is_specialization_of              : std::false_type { };

template<template<typename...> class T, typename... Ts> 
struct is_specialization_of<T, T<Ts...>> : std::true_type  { };

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::cerr << is_specialization_of<std::basic_string, std::string >::value << std::endl;
  std::cerr << is_specialization_of<std::basic_string, std::wstring>::value << std::endl;
  std::cerr << is_specialization_of<std::basic_string, std::istream>::value << std::endl;
}
```

<sup>output</sup>

```
1
1
0
```

---

**solution #2**

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
void strings_only_please(std::basic_string<T1,T2,T3>) {
  // ...  
}
```

Sure, the above won't result in a nice `static_assert` error - but it is sufficient for your needs and does what you want; the function is only callable by types who specialize `std::basic_string`.

---

**solution #3**

```
template<typename T>
struct is_basic_string : std::false_type { };

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
struct is_basic_string<std::basic_string<T1,T2,T3>> : std::true_type { };

...

is_basic_string<std::string >::value // true
is_basic_string<std::istream>::value // false
```

Comment: The first solution won't compile in VS2012? `Error 1 error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '...'` for example

Comment: @WiredPrairie VS2012 doesn't have variadic templates. Try the VS2013 preview.

Comment: @SebastianRedl - I'd like to, but I can't unfortunately install the beta on my workstation.

Comment: @SebastianRedl, You could also try the CTP if you can get that, but it's half-broken, so it's not that great for work really.